# Tomcat can't launch my web application from the war file

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, war, playframework-2.3

My application is originally developed with the Play! framework version 2.3.

I am trying to run my web application from a war file with tomcat 7.

When launching, tomcat logs this:

```
Sep 13, 2015 12:28:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Sep 13, 2015 12:28:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Sep 13, 2015 12:28:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Sep 13, 2015 12:28:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Sep 13, 2015 12:28:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Sep 13, 2015 12:29:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 13, 2015 12:29:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 13170 ms
Sep 13, 2015 12:29:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 13, 2015 12:29:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)
Sep 13, 2015 12:29:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml
Sep 13, 2015 12:29:12 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [177] milliseconds.
Sep 13, 2015 12:29:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/host-manager.xml
Sep 13, 2015 12:29:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/confscheduler.war
Sep 13, 2015 12:29:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Sep 13, 2015 12:29:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/confscheduler] startup failed due to previous errors
Sep 13, 2015 12:29:27 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/confscheduler] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Sep 13, 2015 12:29:27 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/confscheduler] registered the JDBC driver [play.utils.ProxyDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Sep 13, 2015 12:29:27 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/confscheduler] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Sep 13, 2015 12:29:27 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/confscheduler] appears to have started a thread named [BoneCP-keep-alive-scheduler] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Sep 13, 2015 12:29:27 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/confscheduler] appears to have started a thread named [BoneCP-max-alive-scheduler] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Sep 13, 2015 12:29:27 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/confscheduler] appears to have started a thread named [BoneCP-pool-watch-thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Sep 13, 2015 12:29:27 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/confscheduler] appears to have started a thread named [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager@518fdf9] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Sep 13, 2015 12:29:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT
Sep 13, 2015 12:29:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 13, 2015 12:29:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 17500 ms
Sep 13, 2015 12:29:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 13, 2015 12:29:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Sep 13, 2015 12:29:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 13, 2015 12:29:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 13, 2015 12:41:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Sep 13, 2015 12:41:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Sep 13, 2015 12:41:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Sep 13, 2015 12:41:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Sep 13, 2015 12:41:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Sep 13, 2015 12:41:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Sep 13, 2015 12:41:56 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 13, 2015 12:41:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 459 ms
Sep 13, 2015 12:41:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 13, 2015 12:41:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)
Sep 13, 2015 12:41:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml
Sep 13, 2015 12:41:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/host-manager.xml
Sep 13, 2015 12:41:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/confscheduler.war
Sep 13, 2015 12:42:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Sep 13, 2015 12:42:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/confscheduler] startup failed due to previous errors
Sep 13, 2015 12:42:02 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/confscheduler] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Sep 13, 2015 12:42:02 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/confscheduler] registered the JDBC driver [play.utils.ProxyDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Sep 13, 2015 12:42:02 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/confscheduler] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Sep 13, 2015 12:42:02 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/confscheduler] appears to have started a thread named [BoneCP-keep-alive-scheduler] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Sep 13, 2015 12:42:02 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/confscheduler] appears to have started a thread named [BoneCP-max-alive-scheduler] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Sep 13, 2015 12:42:02 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/confscheduler] appears to have started a thread named [BoneCP-pool-watch-thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Sep 13, 2015 12:42:02 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/confscheduler] appears to have started a thread named [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager@7009c732] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Sep 13, 2015 12:42:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT
Sep 13, 2015 12:42:02 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 13, 2015 12:42:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 5882 ms
Sep 13, 2015 12:43:02 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData$9.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1610)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData.getTables(DatabaseMetaData.java:5260)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.isConnectionHandleAlive(BoneCP.java:713)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionTesterThread.run(ConnectionTesterThread.java:103)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Sep 13, 2015 12:43:02 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1610)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent.<init>(LoggingEvent.java:121)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:440)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:396)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.error(Logger.java:559)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionTesterThread.run(ConnectionTesterThread.java:146)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

We can already see many warnings but I don't understand their meaning, some directory doesn't exists but I've installed my tomcat with a traditional `apt-get install` that would have normally install everything I need.

The problem is that I can't make it work, I tried to stop tomcat then move the war file to the webapps directory and start tomcat again: this doesn't launched my app..

Then I connected to the tomcat web application manager, my app (confscheduler) is visible and not running:
[image: Image of the manager where we can see that my webapp (confscheduler) is present]

I tried the start button on the right of my webapp name but after a bit of time the manager showed up this message:
FAIL - Application at context path /confscheduler could not be started

```
FAIL - Application at context path /confscheduler could not be started
```

Here is the part of my catalina.log where we can see my attempt:

```
Sep 12, 2015 9:48:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Sep 12, 2015 9:48:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/confscheduler] startup failed due to previous errors
Sep 12, 2015 9:48:49 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/confscheduler] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Sep 12, 2015 9:48:49 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/confscheduler] registered the JDBC driver [play.utils.ProxyDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Sep 12, 2015 9:48:49 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/confscheduler] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Sep 12, 2015 9:48:49 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/confscheduler] appears to have started a thread named [BoneCP-keep-alive-scheduler] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Sep 12, 2015 9:48:49 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/confscheduler] appears to have started a thread named [BoneCP-max-alive-scheduler] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Sep 12, 2015 9:48:49 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/confscheduler] appears to have started a thread named [BoneCP-pool-watch-thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Sep 12, 2015 9:48:49 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/confscheduler] appears to have started a thread named [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager@6a0b76a6] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

The .war file has been created from my Play! Framework 2.3 Application by using the [play2war](https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin) plugin, I really followed the tutorial of the project but I don't know if the problem comes from the war file or the tomcat servlet.

If you have any idea of what I've done wrong or what could help me getting over this problem please tell me.

Thanks for help

Comment: Are there any more errors above that?   The messsage `startup failed due to previous errors` implies that the error has already occurred when that is shown.

Comment: @Gary I added the launching log that seems to have a lot of warnings and to try a first launch of my app, this may be the previous error told further because this is the only other thing that happened before my try.

Comment: Sometimes, 1x, 2x in a Year i have problems with dynamic undeply/deploy. Maybe singletons give conflict, maybe circular reference, maybe loader cant speak between. Usually JDBC drivers, H2, or ehacache give problem. hard reloading of whole Tomcat give help?

Comment: One plus problem from real life: new deploy takes new versions of framework libraries, when old with no identical structure still live in container.

Comment: @JacekCz do you mean I shall try reloading tomcat?
I already tried this with `service tomcat7 stop/start`.

Comment: Exact same problem here. Did you remember the solution? Was it something like the jdbc-Driver which was not in the /lib folder of tomcat?

Comment: @Spektakulatius, I'm sorry but I didn't find the solution and I left the project short after